# Changing If - Else function to return multiple values?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

So the JavaScript code below is what I am using to pull data from our automated marketing software Eloqua. This works for single-select drop downs. What I want it to do is work for multi-select drop downs.

I know that the ProductValue variable works. So with that said I am positive that it is in the if(ProductValue == ProductList[i].value) specifically the " .value " since this is calling the value on in the drop-downs. Is there a way to make this multiple? This has been driving me nuts for days.

```
function CustomerInformation()

{

var ProductValue = "<span class=eloquaemail>MarketingCustomerInformation1</span>"; //Field Merge...Field merge is working
var ProductList = document.getElementById('C_Marketing_Customer_Information1').options; //Calling the contact record field

for(var i=0; i< ProductList.length; i++) 
    {       
        if(ProductValue == ProductList[i].value) 
            {
                document.getElementById('C_Marketing_Customer_Information1').value = ProductValue;
                break;
            }
        else 
            {
                document.getElementById('C_Marketing_Customer_Information1').value = "Select";
            }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of `break;`?

Comment: Tried this, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you could use multiple for loops:

```
var ProductValue = "<span class=eloquaemail>MarketingCustomerInformation1</span>"; //Field Merge...Field merge is working
var ProductList = document.getElementById('C_Marketing_Customer_Information1').options; //Calling the contact record field

for(var i=0; i< ProductList.length; i++) 
{      
    for(var j=0;j<ProductValue.length;j++)
    {
        if(ProductValue[j] == ProductList[i].value) 
        {
          document.getElementById('C_Marketing_Customer_Information1').option[i].selected="selected";
        }
    }
}
```

Could also add a boolean var to select a default for when nothing gets selected.

**BASIC IDEA**

- The first loop will go through all the values in the multi-select list.
- The second loop will go through all the values you pass it (meaning ProductValue will need to be an array of all the values you want selected).
- IF the current item in the first array (ProductList[i]) is equal to (==) the current item in the second array (ProductValue[j]) THEN you will mark the option as selected.

Some useful tools for your JS needs:

- google
- W3Schools.com
- Firebug (Firefox addon, though most browsers have something tied to F12 that can help, use it to see your variables and step through the functions)

Comment: Sorry my JS is quite limited. Have been pretty much teaching myself it since I started on this project. So with this you are saying running multiple loops? I tried using the code provided inside my function CustomerInformation() but still seem to be coming up with the Field Merge populating with the correct values, but it refuses to pass the values over the multi-select list.

Comment: Here is the code for the multi-select list:
                   <select multiple="" name="C_Marketing_Customer_Information1" id="C_Marketing_Customer_Information1" class="elqField" size="10" style="vertical-align:top;">
          <option value="" selected="selected">--Please Select--</option>         <option value="Apple">Apple</option>          <option value="Carrot">Carrot</option>          <option value="Pear">Pear</option>          <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
         </select>

Comment: How are you calling this function?  Is there a button or are you using cookies or passed parameters or what?